# is releasing objects acceptable on :completion blocks?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, objective-c-blocks

I have an animation block where I move the UIView away from the screen. 
In the completion block I am releasing objects that held that UIView and it's subviews.
Is this acceptable to do?

Comment: it depends on where the completion block executes and what retention is in place.  Views retain their subviews and release them by default when the view is released so there no need to release them on your own.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "release objects"? Are these local variables? instance variables? or what? For local variables, retain and release should always be balanced in the same scope; so retaining outside block and releasing inside block would be wrong. For instance variables, you must make sure to set the instance variable to nil after releasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As a general rule:** If you're careful, this won't have unexpected complications; it's a perfectly understandable thing to do in a completion block.

**In your situation:** Make sure you're not going to overrelease things. Without being able to see the code, I'm not sure when you're doing this in relation to a view's lifecycle. Make sure you understand the processes undertaken when a UIView is destroyed. It would certainly be worth reading: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html